# Created pages not displaying in Top Navigation component

Tags: navigation, publishing-site, top-link-bar, pages, managed-navigation

The *Top Navigation* component should display the contents of the menu defined in the *Navigation* settings. However, I've created several pages (and folders) in my Publishing site which are not appearing in the Top Navigation. The Top Navigation component is empty, providing the ability to add links.

Here are my Navigation settings:
[image]

I have one site collection with a top-level site; no sub-sites. I expected that when I created pages or folders in the page library that they would appear and display.

[image]

What am I missing? (And will the folders display in the navigation?)

*SharePoint 2013 on-premise*

Comment: It will not automatically we have to configure navigation in Term Store management.  Ref link : https://habaneroconsulting.com/insights/Term-based-navigation-in-SharePoint-2013#.VPAJdC4_js0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The navigation options which you have set tries to pulls the items from managed metadata term sets.

Change the Global and Current Navigation settings as below to display the pages as navigation items.
[image]

The folders will not be displayed as navigation items. But you can still add the folders manually and move the pages accordingly under the same navigation settings.
[image]